# Round to the nearest odd multiple of a number

Tags: matlab, math, rounding

is there a MATLAB function that can round to the nearest odd multiple of a number?
For instance, if x = 1.1 and the number is 0.5, then x should be rounded to 1.5

I could come up with a function to round to the nearest multiple but not the nearest odd multiple

```
x = round(x*(1/number))/(1/number);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your approach as follows:

- Use twice the step, that is, `2*number`;
- Shift the input by half of the new step;
- Undo the shifting in the output.

```
y = round((x/(2*number)-.5))*(2*number)+number;
```

Example:

```
number = 2.5;
x = [-10:.01:10];
y = round((x/(2*number)-.5))*(2*number)+number;
plot(x,y)
grid on, axis equal, axis([-15 15 -12.5 12.5])
```

[image]